# Validation date is not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, validation

```
$dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$fieldset->addField(
    'to_date',
    'date',
    [
        'name' => 'to_date',
        'label' => __('From'),
        'title' => __('From'),
        'date_format' => $dateFormat,
        'class' => 'validate-date',
        'required' => false,
        'singleClick' => true
    ]
);
```

Date validation is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: what validation applied here? what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and check it.

```
$dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$fieldset->addField(
    'to_date',
    'date',
    [
        'name' => 'to_date',
        'label' => __('From'),
        'title' => __('From'),
        'date_format' => $dateFormat,
        'validation' => [
            'validate-date' => true
        ],
        'required' => false,
        'singleClick' => true
    ]
);
```

Comment: I have check this, but it is not working